# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha.image'; 'captcha' is not a package

Tags: python, flask, captcha

I am having issue using the **Flask Session Captcha** as the module `flask_session_captcha` seems to call `captcha` in a broken way. The [Catpcha python package](https://pypi.org/project/captcha/) says it will provide `captcha.image` as long as the module `captcha` is installed but it is not working.

I get the following error when I try to launch my Flask app when `flask_session_captcha` tries to load the `captcha.image` module:

```
Error: While importing "captcha", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/devel/Flask/authcaptcha/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/john/devel/Flask/authcaptcha/captcha.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_session_captcha import FlaskSessionCaptcha
  File "/home/john/devel/Flask/authcaptcha/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask_session_captcha/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'captcha.image'; 'captcha' is not a package
```

I have ran `pip install captcha` and version `0.3-py3-none-any` is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't name your module as `capture.py`, it's the same with the package name (`capture`) and it will cause the import conflict.